# Share file from external storage with other app

Tags: android

My application stores it's file in `{external storage}/Documents/myappname/file.anyextension`. This is the kind of url I get when i use `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), MYAPPNAME);`

I'm trying to create an intent to open this file in an other app like the gallery in case it is a picture. Sadly it doesn't work and only open the gallery or makes the app crash. I tried:

- using the real url that File() provide
- Searched to create a FileProvider but it seems it doesn't apply to file located in `{external storage}/Documents` folder. (only cache/internal or external file of the shape `{external storage}/appname` apply

When I pick this file with a filemanager it gives me an url like: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADocuments%2FmyAppName%2Ficon512.png` How can I get such a url ?

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
Intent intentShareFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String filePath = getFilePath();
Log.d(TAG, "shareFileButton: " + filePath);
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(filePath);
intentShareFile.setData(Uri.fromFile(fileWithinMyDir));

if (fileWithinMyDir.exists()) {
  intentShareFile.setType("*/*");

  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentShareFile, "Open file"));
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "file doesn't exist here");
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you have appropriate permission, your code seems fine, though [it will have problems in future versions of Android](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html). You might wish to post the stack trace of whatever problem you are experiencing with this. "only cache/internal or external file of the shape {external storage}/appname apply" -- that's a documentation bug. `<external-path>` points to the root of external storage.

Comment: Here is the intent: `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/appname/icon512.png }` and it either open a chooser, I pick the gallery and it only open the gallery, it doesn't display the picture. If I force the `image/*` mime type it only jumps the picker step.

Comment: If the image is there, that is a problem with the gallery app, not you.

Comment: Found the solution...
From the documentation of setType:


     * <p>This method automatically clears any data that was
     * previously set (for example by {@link #setData}).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution... From the documentation of setType:

This method automatically clears any data that was previously set (for example by {@link #setData}).

Thanks for your help !